# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED while connecting to cosmos DB

Tags: python, database, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-cosmosdb

I am getting an SSL error( SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED  ) while connecting to Cosmos DB. my cosmos DB is present in local network and i am running my python script from ubuntu machine.

Below is the piece of my code:

```
from pydocumentdb import document_client

print('START----------------------')
uri = 'https://10.107.0.111:8081'
key = 'MY_KEY'

client = document_client.DocumentClient(uri, {'masterKey': key})

db_id = 'MY_ID'
db_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(db_id)
db = list(client.QueryDatabases(db_query))[0]
```

Below is ssl error that i am getting:

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.107.0.111', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))
```

[image: WEB_BROWSER_IMAGE_OF_COSMOS_URL]

Looking for help and thanks.

Comment: Hello, did you find the resolution for this problem? I'm facing it right now

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento Actually no, my project was changed and i move forward.

Comment: @Sachya Thanks for the answer, after sometime looking after some solution, i realize that the pydocumentdb lib use urllib3 to make http request and this lib has an option to not validate SSL. Using Azure hosted CosmosDB, it worked fine for me.

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento exactly the same, when i ask from my friend who is working on same he suggest me to set the flag value to false.